# Последовательная анимация блоков

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
.wrap {
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 50px;
  padding: 20%;
}

.card {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 300px;
  height: 80px;
  background: #00d6d6;
}

.card-first{
  top: -30px;
  left: 20px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="card">
    Текст отзыва1
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    Текст отзыва2
  </div>
  <div class="card card-first">
    Текст отзыва3
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    Текст отзыва4
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: что значит перемещаются по кругу? Просто циклически и непрерывно? Или с остановкой? Или какие-то события и обработчики должны быть привязаны? Уточните.

Comment: Непрерывно, как бесконечный слайдер

Comment: т.е. чтобы не успевали прочитать? ))

Comment: Вообще в идеале можно задать любой интервал. И ещё данная анимация больше для оформления в целом ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если число блоков будет переменным, то нужно экспериментировать с задержками и продолжительностями анимации.

```js
window.onload = function() {
  let aCards = document.querySelector('.wrap').children;
  let i = aCards.length;
  while (i--) {
    aCards[i].style.background = 'hsl(' + (i * 60) + ',100%,50%)';
    aCards[i].style.animationDelay = i + 's';
    aCards[i].classList.add('rotator');
  }
}
```

```css
.wrap {
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 50px;
  padding: 20%;
}

.card {
  position: absolute;
  top: -30px;
  left: 20px;
  width: 300px;
  height: 80px;
  border: 2px solid #444;
  opacity: 0.0;
}

.rotator {
  animation: 4s ease-in infinite front;
}

@keyframes front {
  0%   { top: -30px; left: 20px; opacity: 0.0; }
  15%  { top: -30px; left: 20px; opacity: 0.99; z-index: 0; }
  55%  { top: 0px;   left: 0px;                 z-index: 2; }
  70%  { top: 0px;               opacity: 0.99; z-index: 3; }
  99%  { top: 90px;  left: 0px;  opacity: 0.0;  z-index: 4; }
  100% { top: -30px; left: 20px;                z-index: 0; }
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="card">Текст отзыва1</div>
  <div class="card">Текст отзыва2</div>
  <div class="card">Текст отзыва3</div>
  <div class="card">Текст отзыва4</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
setInterval(function(){
  var cardFirst = $('.wrap').find('.card-first'),
      cardFirstIndex = cardFirst.index(),
      nextCard = $('.wrap').find('.card.next');

  cardFirst.removeClass('card-first');
  $(`.card:eq(${nextCard.index()})`).addClass('card-first');

  nextCard.removeClass('next');
  $(`.card:eq(${nextCard.index() - 1})`).addClass('next');
  }, 1000);
```

```css
.wrap {
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 50px;
  padding: 20%;
}

.card {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 300px;
  height: 80px;
  background: #00d6d6;
  transition: all 1s;
  z-index: 11;
}

.card-first{
  top: 30px;
  left: 20px;
  background: red;
  z-index: 13;
}
.next{
  z-index:12;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="card">
    Текст отзыва1
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    Текст отзыва2
  </div>
  <div class="card next">
    Текст отзыва3
  </div>
  <div class="card card-first">
    Текст отзыва4
  </div>
</div>
```

Код не из лучших, но рабочий. За место анимации, сделал переходы в 1с, интервал задается в JS

Answer (score 0):

Советую использовать [Animate.css](https://daneden.github.io/animate.css/) и [wow.js](https://wowjs.uk)

Пример использования:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/aminate.min.css" />

<div class="custom-block wow fadeInUp" data-wow-offset="300"></div>

<script src="js/wow.min.js"></script>
<script>new WOW().init();</script>
```

В конечном итоге, custom-block плавно "выедет" из нижнего края экрана.

Comment: вы описали просто анимацию появления, но не последовательную цикличную анимацию блоков